# ServiceStack - Different server to main application

Tags: servicestack

I wish to create a service which will be hosted on Server A (eg URL: `http://servera:807`). But my main application needs to be hosted on Server B (eg URL: `http://serverb:801`).

I am curious if this is possible or not? The reason my service and main application need to be on different servers are for reasons beyond my control. The current system uses WCF with the same setup and I'd like to move away from this.

In the examples the Service and Client all seem to be hosted in the same location / in the same solution

Comment: We have a similar set up where the web application is a Java application and it calls a Rest service created in C#. The Java application manages user session etc. Are both the services that you mentioned web services? or is one of them web application?

Comment: Server A will be a series ServiceStack services exposing certain data. The one on Server B will be a web application (MVC 4).

Comment: In that case you can have a controller action in your WebApplication, which takes the path of the ServiceStack service to call, the data to pass and Http verb to use. The client can then call this action method with everything needed, and controller action can then call approprite service method with data, get response and pass it back to client. The web application can also manage user session and other request context information.

Comment: Would I have to reference ServiceStack in my Web Application? Also how would my Web Application know what object is being passed back? Or do I simply use `var myObject = ..`

Comment: The web application will be working almost without any intelligence, so it just needs to know where to call the service. It will then simply pass the data to and from client and web application. All the data will can be object or even string (JSON). Or there is an option of doing more work in web application and building a facade for every service method call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a potential set up for solutions/projects. It's simplistic and incomplete but I think helps illustrate one possible set up. You would also need to consider how you want to handle Session information and Authentication since the MVC and ServiceStack handle this separately. See [CustomAuthenticationMVC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases)

**ServerA.sln (ASP.NET Web Application)**

- ServiceModel project - holds requests objects and dtos (this can be shared between ServerA and ServerB solutions)
- ServiceInterface project - has the Service implementations
- Global.asx - has Application_Start method to configure ServiceStack

**ServerB.sln (MV4 application)**

- ServiceModel project (shared)
- Views
- Models
- Controllers

**Example of classes in ServiceModel Project:**

```
[Route("/Foos")]
public class Foos : IReturn<FoosResponse>
{}

public class FoosResponse
{
    public FoosResponse()
    {
        this.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
    }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus {get; set;}
}
```

**Examples of classes in ServiceInterface project**

```
public class FoosService : Service
{
    public FoosResponse Get(Foos request)
    {
        return new FoosReponse();
    }
}
```

**Example how to call ServiceStack API within MVC4 application**

```
public class FoosController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://servera:807");
        var response = client.Get(new Foos());
        return View(response);
    }
}
```